# What is the third(cubic) term of the Taylor expansion of a multivariate function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have seen this for the first and the second term but have never seen the third term. Can anyone write out the third term for me using linear algebra?

Comment: For two variables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Example_in_two_dimensions

Comment: that is good, but not in terms of linear algebra tho

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of expression you are expecting. It's a cubic form, so there's not going to be any nice way of writing it in terms of matrix multiplication (unlike for the linear and quadratic forms in the expansion).